# Gain using single antenna on Aironet 4x4 MIMO device

Tags: cisco, aironet

I'd like to configure a CAP-3602E in order to use with a single element grid antenna.

I assume that when I'm in full 4x4 MIMO mode (all antenna ports enabled), if I have Tx power set at 23dBm, each antenna port is receiving 17dBm (1/4 power).  When I configure to use "a" port, (thus turning off b, c and d) I am wondering what happens in regard to the Tx power.  Is all 23dBm then available at port "a"?  Or will it still only be 17dBm, thus effectively making the radio operate at 1/4 power?